# How to get a specific object onChildClick in an expandablelistview?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have the following problem in my android app(Java):

Each child in the expandablelistview represents an object called Entry,but just the title(child) and a date(header) are stored in the expandablelistview.
When the child is clicked another activity should start, where I can edit the values of the Entry. I need the specific Entry in addition to the new activity if I want to accomplish this feat.

The grand scheme of this is, that each object is an "to-do-task". Each task has a date, title, priority, etc. The tasks are displayed in the expandablelistview  and if you click on a date each task-title with that specific date should show up and if you click on the title another screen should comes up where you can edit the task.

Is there anyway this is possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Here is my expandableListAdapter:

```
ExpandableListAdapter.java
package info.androidhive.expandablelistview;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is my mainactivity:

```
package hartmann.todo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
ListOfEntries listOfEntries;
Gson gson;
int id;
DateFormat dateFormat;
Calendar cal;
Entry entry;
List<String> day0, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, rest;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listOfEntries = new ListOfEntries();
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<>();
    id = 0;
    entry = new Entry();
    gson = new Gson();
    day0 = new ArrayList<>();
    day1 = new ArrayList<>();
    day2 = new ArrayList<>();
    day3 = new ArrayList<>();
    day4 = new ArrayList<>();
    day5 = new ArrayList<>();
    day6 = new ArrayList<>();
    rest = new ArrayList<>();


    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    listDataHeader.add(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    for (int m = 0; m < 6; m++) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        listDataHeader.add(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
    listDataHeader.add("Später");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), day0);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), day1);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), day2);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), day3);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), day4);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), day5);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), day6);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), rest);

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

//  Preparing the list data

private void prepareListData(Entry entry) {


        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal2.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
        cal2.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cal2.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        cal2.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);


        if (entry.getDate().equals(cal2)) {
            day0.add(entry.getTitle());
        }
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        if (entry.getDate().equals(cal2)) {
            day1.add(entry.getTitle());

        }
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        if (entry.getDate().equals(cal2)) {
            day2.add(entry.getTitle());

        }
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        if (entry.getDate().equals(cal2)) {
            day3.add(entry.getTitle());

        }
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        if (entry.getDate().equals(cal2)) {
            day4.add(entry.getTitle());

        }
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        if (entry.getDate().equals(cal2)) {
            day5.add(entry.getTitle());

        }
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        if (entry.getDate().equals(cal2)) {
            day6.add(entry.getTitle());

        }
        if (entry.getDate().after(cal2)) {
            rest.add(entry.getTitle());
        }


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), day0);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), day1);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), day2);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), day3);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), day4);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), day5);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), day6);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), rest);

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

public void newTask(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditEntry.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String strObj = data.getStringExtra("entry");
            entry = gson.fromJson(strObj, Entry.class);
            entry.setEntryId(id);
            id++;
            listOfEntries.addEntry(entry);
            prepareListData(entry);
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult

}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I just edited my post. I can post the rest too if you need anything else.

Comment: Seems like you've posted your adapter twice instead of your MainActivity.

Comment: fixed the mistake